# Magento2.1.7 : Newsletter subscription error?

Tags: error, newsletter, magento-2.1.7

When i add my email to and click on Subscribe button. I get following error

Something went wrong with the subscription.

can someone please help me on this issue?

[image]

Comment: Did you able to solve this issue? I'm also facing the same.

Comment: yes solve it.please check subscription email send or not.@Anjana

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup in Local Setup so that It error Occurs or Not Setup SMTP.

If your setup in local then Please install this extension https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/ and Configure SMTP for Local.

Thanks

Comment: my site is live ..other mails are send but only subscription email are not send @Moin Malek

Comment: which magento version you are used?

Comment: magento ver.2.1.7

Comment: Hello Please debug code in /var/www/html/magento2.2/vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Controller/Subscriber/New Action.php